# Regex for converting mysql sql syntax to sqlite compatible syntax (easy case)

Tags: php, sql, regex, sqlite

i want to convert the following sql query:

```
'UNIQUE KEY `UNIQUE_TAG` (`identifier`,`keyname`)'
```

into this:

```
'CONSTRAINT `UNIQUE_TAG` UNIQUE (`identifier`,`keyname`)'
```

My problem is, i have to grab the first keyword as a var, like this:

```
'<$1> KEY `UNIQUE_TAG` (`identifier`,`keyname`)'
```

to get it here

```
'CONSTRAINT `UNIQUE_TAG` <$1> (`identifier`,`keyname`)'
```

Have a look at http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html to see the syntax of sqlite compatible SQL.

I want to do it in PHP, but i have no idea how to get this done.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I should also mention that the parts of the sql occur within a complete CREATE TABLE statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax wasn't far off.

This example should help:

```
$query = "UNIQUE KEY `UNIQUE_TAG` (`identifier`,`keyname`)";

$regex = "/\b([^ ]+) KEY ([^ ]+) \(([^)]+)\)/";
$substitution = "CONSTRAINT $2 $1 ($3)";

$results = preg_replace($regex, $substitution, $query);

print $results;
```

Some explanation:

- `\b` [matches](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php) a word boundary (beginning of the string or whitespace)
- `[^ ]` matches non-space characters and `[^ ]+` matches non-space characters one or more times
- `(...)` captures whatever `...` is.  This captured group can be referenced in the substitution string by `$1` (since it's the first capture group)
- `[^)]+` matches a string of non-closing parenthesis characters that is at least one character long

Less readable but more generalized matching:

```
$regex = "/\b(\w+)\h+KEY\h+(\H+)\h+\(([^)]+)\)/";
```

Further explanation:

- `\w+` matches one or more "word" characters
- `\h+` matches one or more horizontal whitespace characters (tabs and spaces)
- `\H` matches one or more non-"horizontal whitespace" characters (backticks aren't word characters)

Comment: Thank you - I forgot to mention that this statement is just an example. The keys (in this case: identifier, keyname) and the name of the constraint (in this case: UNIQUE_TAG) can vary from time to time.

Comment: Okay.  I've generalized the constraint name and keys.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex `(UNIQUE )?KEY (.+) (\(.+\))` and replace with `CONSTRAINT $2 $1$3`

```
<?php
$sourcestring="UNIQUE KEY `UNIQUE_TAG` (`identifier`,`keyname`)";
echo preg_replace('/(UNIQUE )?KEY (.+) (\(.+\))/','CONSTRAINT $2 $1$3',$sourcestring);
?>
```

http://www.myregextester.com/?r=83cd23ec